# intercept attribute modifications in Python class

Tags: python, attributes

I want to implement a class in Python where modifying a subset of its attributes leads to a specific class method being called. I see that Python offers many ways to achieve something what I want but I'm not sure which is the most Pythonic and minimalistic way to achieve this.

For instance, let's say we have class `Foo` with attributes `x`, `y`, `z`, and we're interested in intercepting modifications to attributes `x` and `y`. Whenever someone calls `foo.x = ...` or `foo.y = ...`, I want method `foo.bar` to be called. Also, I don't really care if I have to use a wrapper for each attribute, provided that this wrapper would have to be written only once, e.g. somehow intercept calls to virtually non-existent methods `foo.set_x(...)` and `foo.set_y(...)` to `def foo.set_member(self, member, value): ...`.

Comment: So you want [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's exactly what I need, I missed the part that explains how to actually access the member once inside the ```__setattr__``` function. However, it turns out that having a ```set_XXX``` method (were the ```XXX``` part of the method name is resolved dynamically) would suit my needs better. Unfortunately, it looks like that Python doesn't give me a chance via some mechanism to intercept a method call, it immediatelly fails with ```AttributeError```.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy with the new classes in Python, built on top of the `object` class :

```
class Foo ( object ) :

    def __setattr__ ( self, name, value ) :
        self.bar( name, value )
        object.__setattr__( self, name, value )

    def bar ( self, name, value ) :
        print( 'Setting {} to {}.'.format( name, value ) )
```